# Front page redirects to user page

Tags: 8

I just installed D8, but when I try to reach the Front Page as an authenticated user, I got immediately redirected (302) to the user page. As a anonymous user, it works as expected.

I do not know exactly what additional data I should provide for debugging this issue, but will happly provided any information I can.

Comment: Have you installed any modules? When you sya Front Page you mean that you goto http://example.com/, using your custom domain, but nothing else afeter domain name, right?

Comment: is this a fresh drupal install with 0 contrib modules? if not when did it start?

Comment: Fresh install, 0 contrib modules. By fronrt page I mean example.com, nothing after that.

Comment: what *is*  the default frontpage? Did you install standard or minimal? Minimal does not have the frontpage view, and the default frontpage is /user. which redirects to the user if you are logged in.

Comment: This nailed it, i used the minimal profile. How can I create the frontpage view then?

Comment: @rbaprado same problem to me. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215986/unable-to-access-default-front-page-node-as-admin

Answer (score 1):

In the "Default front page" field at /admin/config/system/site-information, instead of leave it blank, insert /node which is normally what drupal places by default.

Comment: This answer assumes that `/node` is a valid path. I don't think it even exists if you installed Drupal with the minimal profile.